# Update Panel In Asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

In my web application there is a page, where video will play problem is when i click on any button or link the video start from the first time i place the update panel, in that i place div and place the object code of jw player. this is my code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myupd" runat ="Server" UpdateMode="conditional">         
     <ContentTemplate >
      <div id="dvplayer" runat ="server" ></div>
     </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>                        
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional" >                            
      <ContentTemplate >
        <asp:Button ID="btn" runat ="Server" Text ="ok" />
      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Can u help me? I write like this in update panel UpdateMode="Conditional" but it is not working.

Comment: Your `UpdatePanel` just contains a `DIV` not a "object code for jw player". May be you have not pasted correct code.

Comment: @afsharm i not place the object code is it necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Are you putting the player within an update panel?  Do you need to put the player in one?  If you don't, it shouldn't be potentially interrupted by the external events that run async...

HTH.